# Symfony check if request to controller came from a fragment

Tags: symfony

In Symfony is there a way to check if the request came from a fragment include such as:

```
 {% render url('call_to_route') %}
```

I don't have to duplicate my route to accommodate for the fragment include.

Thanks!

Comment: $request->getRequestType() !== HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I found a solution but I'm not sure about it:
Seems that a request from a fragment has a "`_fragment`" string in the URI, so this code seems to work but note that I'm not sure and any other request with the string "`_fragment`" in it will match with 1st case.

```
class myController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    if (strpos($request->server->get('REQUEST_URI'), "_fragment")) {
        return new Response('Request from a fragment');
    }
    elseif ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        return new Response('Request from ajax');
    }
    else {
        return new Response('normal request');
    }
}
```

I'm interested if anybody knows if there's a better solution -  `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()`, maybe there's something similar for a fragment? I'm still searching, sorry for my English.

Comment: in my case `if('/_fragment' === $request->getPathInfo()) {...` works

Answer (score 0):

It'as actually a bad thing, because fragment can rely on cache, or on other software like Varnish or Nginx.

So it's a better way to include a parameter in your URL or to have different URLs.